Binary Search with Probabilistic Comparison Errors
In a standard binary search on a sorted array, when you compare the item being searched ($x$) with the pivot ($m$), if $x < m$, then you recurse in the first half of the array; if $x > m$, then you recurse in the second half of the array;
I'm looking for literature on binary search where the comparison function isn't always accurate, i.e., doesn't give you perfect information on which side to recurse.
Specifically, I'm looking for the following: let's say we have a comparator $C(\cdot, \cdot)$.
If $C(x,m) = -1$, then $x$ will be in the first part of the array with 100% probability
If $C(x,m) = 0$, then we've found $x = m$
If $C(x,m) = 1$, then $x$ will be in the first part of the array with probability $p$ and in the second part with probability $1-p$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search#Noisy_binary_search

What is the algorithm used to implement $C$?  In particular, if $x<m$, what is the probability that $C(x,m)=-1$ and the probability that $C(x,m)=1$?  (What if $m<pn$ where $n$ is the length of the array?  Then your specification does not seem achievable?)

Thanks. Is there a version with only one-sided errors? So if the comparison says xm, the truth is that it is actually xm with probability 1-p

The comparator is a black box. I'm using C(x,m) =-1 (resp 1) as the comparator claiming that x<m (resp x>m). When the comparator claims x>m, it is incorrect with probability p

Thank you for your response.  I think I understand the intent, but I don't think you've fully appreciated some of my comments yet.  If $m<pn$, where $n$ is the length of the array, then I believe it is not possible to build a comparator with the properties you want it to have.  So please specify how $C$ operators -- not just what we can infer from its output, but what randomized algorithm $C$ uses to produce an output, given the inputs.
